# How to reset auto increment number every year in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model `IncomingCorrespondence` with auto incrementing field **`ID`**. I also have field **`number`**, and I want two things for this field:

1. This field will auto-increment its value, just like **`ID`**
2. Every new year its value will start over from 0 (or 1)

| ID | Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| … | … | … |
| 285 | 285 | 2020-03-12 |
| 286 | 286 | 2020-04-19 |
| 287 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |

```py
class IncomingCorrespondence(models.Model):
   ID = models.models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   date = models.DateField(null=True)
   number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

How can I do that the most efficient and reliable way?

Comment: I guess so, the ```number``` field is not demanding to be unique, so that shouldn't make any problem I suppose...

Comment: Hello, so what did you try to do that, or what ideas do you have? Did you try anything?

Comment: I got you, didn't get the question from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store the number, you can simply derive it by the number of items that are stored in the database since it has turned that year with:

```
class IncomingCorrespondence(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def number(self):
        return IncomingCorrespondence._base_manager.filter(
            created__year=self.created.year,
            created__lt=self.created
        ).count() + 1
```

We thus have a timestamp `created` that will store at what datetime the object was created, and we count the number of `IncomingCorrespondence` for that year before the timestamp plus one. You can in that case work with a package like [**`django-softdelete`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete) to keep deleted objects in the database, and just filter these out when viewing the item.

another way might be to assign the maximum plus one to a field:

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.utils.timezone import now

def next_number():
    data = IncomingCorrespondence._base_manager.filter(
        date__year=now().year
    ).aggregate(
        max_number=Max('number')
    )['max_number'] or 0
    return data + 1

class IncomingCorrespondence(models.Model):
   ID = models.models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   number = models.IntegerField(default=next_number, editable=False)
```

But here Django will dispatch numbers through a query. If there are multiple threads that concurrently create an `IncomingCorrespondence`, then this can fail. It also depends on the *insertion* time, not the `date` of the `IncomingCorrespondence` object.

Comment: I think you can do this with `created__range=(self.created.year, self.created)` which will be nicer

Comment: That solution seems to be the good one, but what would happen If one or more elements will be deleted from the database? I guess the ```number``` value on the other ones will be changed too, right?

Comment: @sudden_appearance: you can not use `.year` as a start, since that is an `int`. Furthermore it would also include the `self.created` in the timespan (which is inclusive) so it would give a different answer depending or not the object is already saved in the database.

Comment: @NIKITOS: yes, it will reindex the values (well not proactively, it simply will obtain a different number if it calculates its number).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. It is necessary for me that a number is strictly assigned to each object and it would not depend on other elements (would not be changed when other objects are changed or deleted) =(

Comment: @NIKITOS: you can work with a softdelete package like [`django-softdelete`](https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete) to not really remove the item, but simply no longer see the entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should count `number` with some method like querying count of created `IncomingCorrespondence` this year. It should not be done any other way (cronjob for example) as it won't be stable (crontab may fail and you will end up with anomalies (and won't even be able to notice that), or you will create instance right before crontab reset the sequence)

Comment: Is there a way to ```.count``` or get ```nextval``` objects in database even if they were removed. What I mean is, I need some part (for example ID) that remains in the table even after deleting other elements in order to already count from this field